# My bone isn't moving the part it's weight painted to for some reason

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I have a model, and part of the model is separated and is able to be moved. It's weight painted red for both the main bone and for the individual bone controlling it, but when I try to move the bone controlling it, it's only moved half way. I tried coloring the separated part blue on the main bone's vertex group, but that makes it unmovable by any bone, including the individual bone meant for it, despite it still being red within that vertex group, How can I make it so I can move the separated part of the mesh? The individual bone is parented to the main bone

Comment: Some of the things you mentioned in your question sound impossible. One of us is misunderstanding something. Please add details such as screenshots of relevant vertex groups as they appear in Weight Paint Mode, and the whole armature with show bone names turned on for the viewport. If all else fails, use blend-exchange.com to edit the file into your question.

Comment: Based on your reiteration on my (deleted) answer, yeah please do share the file. This sounds really strange.